# How do I select oldest date values per group while using DateSerial function in Microsoft Access, using SQL?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, office365, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select the earliest date out of a group of records with the same userID. However, the date field I'm using was in a string format organized as such: yyyymmdd. 
So I used the DateSerial function to convert the dates to this format: mm/dd/yyyy. That was step one. Step two (which is where I need some help) is the grouping of UserIDs by oldest date. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Current query:

SELECT 
    [userID], 
    [company], 
    DateSerial(Left([DateOfSale], 4), Mid([DateOfSale], 5, 2), Right([DateOfSale], 2)) AS SaleDate
FROM mytable
```

Result:

```
|userID| company  | SaleDate    |
_________________________________
|1     | catworld | 01/01/2005  |
|1     | catworld | 01/03/2017  |
|2     | fishworld| 05/05/2019  |
|3     | dogworld | 02/01/2005  |
|3     | dogworld | 02/03/2017  |
```

Desired Result:

```
|userID| company  | SaleDate    |
_________________________________
|1     | catworld | 01/01/2005  |
|2     | fishworld| 05/05/2019  |
|3     | dogworld | 02/01/2005  |
```

Comment: With dates, `yyyymmdd` and `mm/dd/yyyy` maintain same values just different formats.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`CDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/type-conversion-functions) which can cast date strings to actual date/time values. However because `yyymmdd` is not a valid date format, add hyphens between date parts for proper casting. And do so at the table level with a new column. See DDL commands to be run separately or using Access GUI (table design > new field):

```
ALTER TABLE main_table ADD COLUMN Saledate_Actual Date;

UPDATE main_table SET SaleDate_Actual = CDate(
                                              LEFT([DateOfSale], 4) & '-' &
                                              MID([DateOfSale], 5, 2) & '-' &
                                              RIGHT([DateOfSale], 2)
                                             );
```

Then join an aggregate query to the main table.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM main_table m
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT userID, MIN(Saledate_Actual) AS min_date
    FROM main_table
    GROUP BY userID) AS agg
ON m.userID = agg.userID
AND m.Saledate_Actual = agg.min_date
```

Maybe once day MS Access will have window functions. Please upvote my request to [MS Access team](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (no need to log in to vote)!

```
SELECT m.*
FROM main_table m
WHERE m.Saledate_Actual = MIN(Saledate_Actual) OVER(PARTITION BY userID)
```

Comment: I would think you may still need the current `DateSerial()` expression in order to convert to a date... No?

Comment: Did you read my intro suggesting to use `CDate` and to update table design with a new field of actual date/times? Then, OP can query directly the new column. Otherwise, replace *Saledate_Actual* with `CDate(SaleDate)`.

Comment: I did read that. My concern is that I still think you need to use `DateSerial()` when you are altering the table and adding a new column in your first query...

Comment: Why `DateSerial` and not `CDate` designed to cast strings to dates? See posted link.

Comment: Right, sorry to be unclear. I think you need to use both... So `CDate(DateSerial(Left..,mid..right..))`... Because I don't think yyyymmdd is a valid date format is it?

Comment: Ah! Yes, @BJones, thank you my friend. I updated accordingly by adding hyphens for proper date format.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was missing.

Comment: @Parfait I did step one and it worked (CDate part). Although I didn't get mm-dd-yyyy format. Instead I got mm/dd/yyyy. That aside, I'm completely new to Access and still learning SQL. I'm a little lost here: `SELECT m.*
FROM main_table m` Specifically what does the "m" specify in both areas of the query? Anyhow, I tried it and I got "JOIN expression not supported." Thanks.

Comment: You can easily [custom format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-and-time-field-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698#bkmk_apply_custom) stored dates in table to `mm-dd-yyyy`. But as commented above, the underlying date value does not change just its screen presentation. As for `m` in this solution, that is the [table alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/alias.php) to avoid re-typing full table name. I see I left out a `m` on `Saledate_Actual`. See slight edit. Be sure to replace these with actual table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a correlated subquery. The good thing about the current format of your string dates (`yyyymmdd`) is that it can be properly sorted, so this should just work:

```
select
    [userID], 
    [company], 
    DateSerial(Left([DateOfSale], 4), Mid([DateOfSale], 5, 2), Right([DateOfSale], 2)) AS SaleDate
from mytable t
where t.SaleDate = (
    select min(t1.[SaleDate]) from mytable t1 where t1.[userID] = t.[userID]
)
```

Comment: Doesn't correlated aggregate queries run for every row?

Comment: @Parfait: ms-access is not my strongest skill, however in most RDBMS that I know about this is one of the the most efficient method to solve the greatest-n-per-group problem (often more efficient than the aggregate and join approach).

Comment: *Really*? A correlated aggregate query efficient? Let me read on this one...

Comment: @GMB I tried this too and I get the following popup message: _Enter Parameter Value ? t1.SaleDate._ It gives me the option to enter something (not sure what) and press OK. If I press OK I get one more box saying the same thing but with _t.SaleDate._ I hit OK. The query runs but returns nothing...